# Processing 2: Random text from array to appear on click?

Tags: java, arrays, string, processing

The movie quotes are just appearing randomly in quick succession rather than the desired effect of it pulling one random movie quote from the text document.

Ideally I want a new quote to appear by the click of the mouse.

Tried to make the array and index a global variable but then the text wouldn't display for some reason.

```
PImage wallpaper;



 void setup() {
 size(600, 600);
 wallpaper = loadImage("Theatrescreen.png");  
 }

 void draw() {
 background(wallpaper);
 String[] moviequotes = loadStrings("moviequotes.txt");
 int index = int(random(moviequotes.length));
 text(moviequotes[index], mouseX, mouseY);  
 }

 void mousePressed() {

 }
```

Comment: If you are using Processing 2, [this](https://processing.org/reference/random_.html) should be of help to you. If you look, I believe there's an example showing exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That's the one I attempted to use, however I made a mess of it. As it isn't bringing just one random quote from my text file but going through all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code within `draw()` is executed in an infinite loop. I think that is your problem. See [Processing Reference - draw()](https://processing.org/reference/draw_.html). To take care of the problem, consider using `noloop()`. See [Processing Reference - noloop()](https://processing.org/reference/noLoop_.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of Random isn't correct. Try something like this:

```
void draw() {
    background(wallpaper);
    String[] moviequotes = loadStrings("moviequotes.txt");
    Random randIndex = new Random();
    int index = randIndex.nextInt(moviequotes.length); // generate a random index from 0 to movieqoutes.length
    text(moviequotes[index], mouseX, mouseY);  
    }
```

Comment: Now if you want a different qoute for each mouse click you will have to move some code around, and probably make `moviequotes` global.

Comment: Tried to implement that but I'm getting the error "Cannot find a class or type named Random". Thanks for the response!

Comment: Oh sorry, add this `import java.util.Random;` and try it again?

Comment: Good news and bad, so it functions. But functions the same way my code did. Displays random quotes quickly, one after the other.

Comment: After seeing DavidB's comment, it looks like he is right. I failed to observe that Processing 2 has a Random function like what you're trying to do. Either way works though, as you witnessed. Is `draw()` getting called over and over somewhere?

Comment: Not that i'm aware of. [Here's a link to it hosted on Dropbox if you want to have a closer look](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nlk0bk857ng6s87/AADCawJl5c0rcBm_rUpSG56Ha?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

You are generating a new random movie quote each draw cycle. That means a lot (more than 25 dependeing on framerate) each second.

You can set the framerate like this:

```
 void setup() {
   frameRate(1);
 }
```

or add a counter to your draw loop, so that you generate a new quote only once in a while